# Why is it evbuffer_add_printf will only accept static variables and not "dynamic" ones?

Tags: c, libevent, libev

So far I have gotten my *libev* code to successfully return a static sting that says "OMP OMP", however when I write a function that returns a "static" string it never seems to work. (Sidenote: the idea is to turn that same function into a dynamic response but just for agile testing purposes I need this to work first). My code for the *libev* read callback is as the following...

```
void p2pserver_network_buf_read_callback(struct bufferevent *incoming, void *arg){
    //Define function local variables
    struct evbuffer *evreturn;
    char *req;

    //Begin function local logic
    req = evbuffer_readline(incoming->input);
    if (req == NULL){
        return;    
    }


    char *response;
    parse_json_command(req, response);
    //response = "OMP OMP";
    g_print("PARSED");
    evreturn = evbuffer_new();
    evbuffer_add_printf(evreturn, "%s", response);

    bufferevent_write_buffer(incoming,evreturn);
    evbuffer_free(evreturn);
    free(req);

    g_print("%s", response);
}
```

The parse_json_command **function** is as the following...

```
void parse_json_command(char json_command, char *response){

    //Define Local Variables
    g_print("PARSING");

    response = "YOU KNOW";

    //Print out the recieved message....
    //g_message("%s", json_command);


    /** 
     * TODO: check if the JSON is valid before parsing 
     *          to prevent "Segmentation Defaults" 
     *          and its good sanity checks.
     **/

    //Parse JSON incomming
    /*json_object * jobj = json_tokener_parse(json_command);

    enum json_type type;
    json_object_object_foreach(jobj, key, val){
        g_print("%s\n", key);

        if(g_utf8_collate(key, "cmd") >= 0){
            //Looks like the user has sent a "cmd" (command), lets analyze the "val" (value) of that command to see what the caller/client needs to be attending to...

            //Is the client requesting an "Identity Update" (Pings server: if this is the first time ping, the server and client will exachange keys if the relationship exists the server just accepts the encrypted "ping" packet update)
            type = json_object_get_type(val);
            if(type == json_type_string){
                char* cmd_value;
                cmd_value = json_object_get_string(val);
                //g_print("VALUE:%d\n", g_utf8_collate(cmd_value, "identupdate"));
                if(g_utf8_collate(cmd_value, "identupdate") == 0){
                    //Call "Identity Update Response"
                        //char return_response = p2pserver_json_identupdate_response(json_command);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    */
    return;
}
```

If you want to see the complete code (only a couple of pages big at the time of this writing) you can go to the source code at the following link: https://github.com/Xenland/P2PCrypt-Server

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200595/transfer-the-data-between-shared-library-and-application/14200674#14200674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c passes arguments by value, not by reference. You problem is here:

```
void parse_json_command(char json_command, char *response){
    [...]
    response = "YOU KNOW";
    [...]
}

char *response;
parse_json_command(req, response);
```

`response` is a uninitialized pointer to a string. You are assigning a pointer to a static string to the `response` pointer in the function, but that does not modify `response` outside of the function, it just changes `response` within the function.  There are different ways to fix this. Probably the easiest one for a quick fix would be to change the function's prototype to return a `char *` instead of `void`:

```
char * parse_json_command(char json_command){
    char *response;
    [...]
    response = "YOU KNOW";
    [...]
    return response;
}

char *response;
response = parse_json_command(req);
```

Also, the `json_command` argument should probably be a `char *` or `const char *`, not just a single `char`, if you want to pass more than a single byte there.

Comment: Thanks that was actually my first solution and I thought I did it wrong and tried the solution you see now, oddly enough though I copied and pasted your answer and it worked great, I must have had spelling mistakes somewhere since I've been at this for almost 16 hours trying to get past this part. Cheers man!